# Bootstrap not all glyphicons available

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm having a lot of trouble showing a few specific bootstrap glyphicons. I realize that this question has been repeated a few times, but it doesn't seem like those solutions work for every glyphicon in bootstrap.

I am totally unable to show "glyphicon-sunglasses" and "glyphicon-lamp". I am using version 3.3.2, and I have tried replacing my fonts directory with a fresh one from the bootstrap .zip file.

Are not all of the 260 glyphicons on the components page available?

Comment: All [258](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/15688) of them are available.

Comment: Any thoughts on why many would not show for me?

Comment: Wrong font URL? Any errors in the network tab or JS console? What browser and OS? Does it work if you use http://www.bootstrapcdn.com ?